# Why isn't my inner loop working correctly?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm relatively new with the Pandas data frames. I have the following code and For nested loop.

The problem arises when the loop hits the inner loop.

```
import pandas as pd 

### Create Data Frames:
Patients = {'Name': ['Jordan','Jess', 'Jake', 'Alice', 'Alan', 'Lauren'], 'Age': [26,23,19,20,24,28],'Sex': ['M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F'],
            'BMI': [26,22,24,17,35,20],'Smokes': ['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No']}

pdf = pd.DataFrame(Patients)
print(pdf) ## DF printed out completely 

## 
i = 0

for Smokes in pdf.Smokes:
    if Smokes == 'Yes':
        pdf.at[i, 'Risk'] = 'high'
    else: 
       pdf.at[i, 'Risk'] = ' '
       for BMI in pdf.BMI:
           if BMI >= 30 or BMI <= 19:
               pdf.at[i, 'Risk'] = 'high'
           elif BMI >= 25 and BMI <=29:
               pdf.at[i, 'Risk'] = 'medium'
           else: 
               pdf.at[i, 'Risk'] = 'Low'
    i +=1 #
```

However, when I print out the pdf again, it shows:

```
   Name  Age Sex  BMI Smokes  Risk
0  Jordan   26   M   26     No   Low
1    Jess   23   F   22     No   Low
2    Jake   19   M   24    Yes  high
3   Alice   20   F   17     No   Low
4    Alan   24   M   35    Yes  high
5  Lauren   28   F   20     No   Low
```

Jordan should be a medium risk and Alice should be low risk patient but the inner loop is not recognizing that. However, when I run the BMI loop separately, it recognizes it.

Comment: it doesn't seem you need that inner loop at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first `else` statement you have a `for` loop that is evaluating again all the `Risk` values you should use your code without the inner `for` loop:

```
if Smokes == 'Yes':
    pdf.at[i, 'Risk'] = 'high'
elif pdf.at[i, 'BMI'] >= 30 or pdf.at[i, 'BMI'] <= 19:
       pdf.at[i, 'Risk'] = 'high'
elif pdf.at[i, 'BMI'] >= 25 and pdf.at[i, 'BMI'] <=29:
       pdf.at[i, 'Risk'] = 'medium'
else: 
    pdf.at[i, 'Risk'] = 'Low'
```

with these small changes in your code pdf will be:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't loop. Use `np.select` to create the hierarchy of conditions and the corresponding choices and assign the correct value. It gives precedence to the first `True` found in conditions so we order it `'high'`, `'medium'`, `'low'`.

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [df['Smokes'].eq('Yes') | df['BMI'].ge(30) | df['BMI'].le(19),  # high
              df['BMI'].between(25, 30)]                                     # medium
choice_list = ['high', 'medium']

df['Risk'] = np.select(conditions, choice_list, default='low')
```

---

```
     Name  Age Sex  BMI Smokes    Risk
0  Jordan   26   M   26     No  medium
1    Jess   23   F   22     No     low
2    Jake   19   M   24    Yes    high
3   Alice   20   F   17     No    high
4    Alan   24   M   35    Yes    high
5  Lauren   28   F   20     No     low
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth refactoring your code into something like

```
def get_risk(row):
    if row['Smokes'] == 'Yes':
        return 'high'
    elif row['BMI'] >= 30 or row['BMI'] <= 19:
        return 'high'
    elif row['BMI'] >= 25 and row['BMI'] <=29:
        return 'medium'
    else:
        return 'low'

pdf['Risk'] = pdf.apply(get_risk, axis=1)
```

I am not sure whether the logic in your risk calculation gives you what you expect though. I copied it verbatim from your example.

Answer (score 1):

Often when using pandas dataframes, there are efficient ways to complete tasks without using `for` loops. In your case, you can define a function that returns the 'Risk' value string and `apply` it across the columns of each row to set the desired new column:

```
import pandas as pd 

# create dataframe
Patients = {'Name': ['Jordan','Jess', 'Jake', 'Alice', 'Alan', 'Lauren'], 'Age': [26,23,19,20,24,28],'Sex': ['M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F'],
            'BMI': [26,22,24,17,35,20],'Smokes': ['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No']}
pdf = pd.DataFrame(Patients)
# inspect dataframe
print(pdf)

# define the function that you want to apply
def get_risk(series):

    if series.Smokes == 'Yes':
        return 'high'    
    else:
        if series.BMI >= 30 or series.BMI <= 19:
            return 'high'
        elif series.BMI >= 25 and series.BMI <= 29:
            return 'medium'
        else:
            return 'low'

# apply the function across the columns of the dataframe (sending each row to the function as a series)
pdf['Risk'] = pdf.apply(get_risk, axis='columns')

# inspect the results
print(pdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner for loop finishes and sets `pdf.at[i, 'Risk'] = 'Low'` because the last BMI (20) is good. This happens on every loop of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 

### Create Data Frames:
Patients = {'Name': ['Jordan','Jess', 'Jake', 'Alice', 'Alan', 'Lauren'], 'Age': [26,23,19,20,24,28],'Sex': ['M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F'],
        'BMI': [26,22,24,17,35,20],'Smokes': ['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No']}

pdf = pd.DataFrame(Patients)

risk = []
for index,rows in pdf.iterrows():
    if rows['Smokes'] == 'Yes':
          risk.append('high')
    else: 
       BMI = rows['BMI']
       if BMI >= 30 or BMI <= 19:
             risk.append('high')
       elif BMI >= 25 and BMI <=29:
             risk.append('medium')
       else: 
             risk.append('Low') 
pdf['risk']=risk
```

Explanation: iterrows() helps to iterate over each row of the dataframe. 'rows' will contain all the values. P.S Alice will be on High risk given your condition as BMI is lower than 19. I have considered a separate list 'risk' where I am appending values for each row & finally adding this column in the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Use it instead of for loop, it is very clean and fast:

```
import numpy as np
pdf['Risk'] = np.where(pdf['Smokes']=='Yes', 'High','none')

pdf['Risk'] = np.where(np.logical_and(pdf['Smokes']=='No', pdf['Age']==26), 'medium','none')
```